# Flutter/Dart Formatting for in-line Documentation Comments?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, documentation

Are there additional formatting options for Flutter/Dart in-line documentation?

I'm using Android Studio. I prefer to leave detailed comments so I don't have to spend time looking through code to figure out why a specific class or method was used. In C#, I use the triple-slash (///) with  to add in-line documentation. I know Dart uses the triple-slash as well, but slightly differently than C#. For instance, Dart doesn't support the Summary, Para, nor Param tags.

From what I have found, Dart uses the following:

Of course, triple-slash (///) is a basic in-line documentation comment

```
/// My Documentation Comment
```

I've found that you can use plus (+) or minus (-) to indicate an item in a bulleted list:

```
/// - Bullet List Item 1
/// + Bullet List Item 2
```

You can also use Hash (#) for emphasizing a line.

```
/// # This Line will be Emphasized
```

Lastly, it supports the BR tag for new line in comments.

```
/// This is line 1 
/// This will also appear on line 1
/// <br /> This will appear on line 2
```

Apart from these 4, are there any other formatting options that can be performed when working with in-line documentation in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dartdoc uses Markdown](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#markdown), so you can use most typical Markdown formatting in Dartdoc comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use **TODO** in Comments.
The **TODO** will make it highlight and accessible

```
///TODO:something in comment
```

This works fine with android studio

Comment: I use Intellij Idea, so I assume this would be true in Android Studio. There are a number of options in the gutter, eg Git | Run | Messages | Terminal, etc. One is TODO. This can be configured to show all TODOs in the project, int current file, in changelist, and scope. Very handy. I use it frequently.